Issue with Email Templates Overwriting Content in Vtiger CRM
I'm encountering an issue with Vtiger CRM's Email Templates feature. Whenever I select a template in the Email Templates module, it overwrites any existing content in the CKEditor field, even if there is already content present.
I'm encountering an issue with Vtiger CRM's Email Templates feature. Whenever I select a template in the Email Templates module, it overwrites any existing content in the CKEditor field, even if there is already content present.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution to prevent the selected template from overwriting existing content in the CKEditor field?
I've tried modifying the JavaScript code responsible for handling template selections, but the problem persists. "layouts\v7\modules\EmailTemplates\resources\Edit.js"

Well, I think that's the way it works. I guess you are supposed to first select a template and then modify it if necessary on the ckeditor. After all is a template, not a macro.

I understand that this is how it currently works, but is there no way to edit the code so that it doesn't overwrite the existing information and instead merges it?

You can edit the function that inserts the template on ckeditor. It's on the file:
layouts/v7/modules/Vtiger/resources/CkEditor.js

Search for the function:
loadContentsInCkeditor : function(contents){
    var CkEditor = this.getCkEditorInstanceFromName();
    CkEditor.setData(contents);
},

and change it to something like this:
loadContentsInCkeditor : function(contents){
    var CkEditor = this.getCkEditorInstanceFromName();

    // append to actual content
    contents = CkEditor.document.getBody().getHtml() + contents;
    CkEditor.setData(contents);
},

Hope this helps!
